# Azure Application Gateway health probe error with "Backend server certificate is not whitelisted with Application Gateway"

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have created an application gateway with 3 backend nodes, when I set the "Http Listener" with all the 3 nodes certificates, the health probe is green. However when I replace all the 3 certificates to my CA cert, it goes red and warm me "Backend server certificate is not whitelisted with Application Gateway"
The reason why I try to use CA cert is that I manage all the resource in terraform, with a single CA cert, it is better to automate the process

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need a Default SITE binding to a [`certificate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-end-to-end-ssl-powershell), without SNI ticked. Here is a blog post to fix the [issue](https://craigclouditpro.wordpress.com/2019/04/05/azure-application-gateway-502-web-server-backend-certificate-not-whitelisted/).